# How to Build Camera app Separately from AOSP?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-camera, android-source, photosphere

I need to build an Android app to capture panorama images similar to how Photo Sphere feature of Android 4.2+ Camera app.

I tried to look into the Android Open Source Project specifically at [PanoramaModule](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r1/com/android/camera/PanoramaModule.java#PanoramaModule), and downloaded the entire source of the [Camera app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera/), but failed to build it as an Android project in Eclipse because of missing references. For instance...

- com.android.gallery3d
- @layout/gl_root_group

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you found the missing libraries? I got the code from Git Repository but having same errors you did. I also need documentation for code. Can i find documentation for this code. I need to know how FocusOverlayManager and PierRenderer classes work.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the root of the source code and use "make Camera" command to build that app.